# Row Validation with Jquery Validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have a series of forms that correspond to likert questions:

```
<form class="indicator-form" request="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label class="top-label">
            Enter the number of <strong>category 1</strong> staff that answered each level of importance on a 5-point likert-field scale for the question:<br/>
            <em>Question 1?</em>
        </label>
        <table>
            <tr class="likert">
                <td>
                    <label for="cat1_a">Very Unimportant</label>
                    <input id="cat1_a" name="cat1_a" class="likert-field" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="cat1_b">Unimportant</label>
                    <input id="cat1_b" name="cat1_b" class="likert-field" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="cat1_c">Neutral</label>
                    <input id="cat1_c" name="cat1_c" class="likert-field" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="cat1_d">Important</label>
                    <input id="cat1_d" name="cat1_d" class="likert-field" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="cat1_e">Very Important</label>
                    <input id="cat1_e" name="cat1_e" class="likert-field" type="text" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <label class="top-label">
            Enter the number of <strong>category 2</strong> staff that answered each level of importance on a 5-point likert-field scale for the question:<br/>
            <em>Question 2?</em>
        </label>
        <table>
            <tr class="likert">
                <td>
                    <label for="cat2_a">Very Unimportant</label>
                    <input id="cat2_a" name="cat2_a" class="likert-field" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="cat2_b">Unimportant</label>
                    <input id="cat2_b" name="cat2_b" class="likert-field" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="cat2_c">Neutral</label>
                    <input id="cat2_c" name="cat2_c" class="likert-field" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="cat2_d">Important</label>
                    <input id="cat2_d" name="cat2_d" class="likert-field" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="cat2_e">Very Important</label>
                    <input id="cat2_e" name="cat2_e" class="likert-field" type="text" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Data"/>
</form>
```

I want to validate each table row so that:

- If there is no data in the row, no validation is applied (i.e. a user
  can submit an empty row)
- If there is *any* data in the row, all fields must be filled out.

My JS:

```
// Likert Row Validation
jQuery.validator.addMethod('likert', function(value, element) {
    var $inputs = $(element).closest('tr.likert').find('.likert-field:filled');

    if (0 < $inputs.length && $inputs.length < 5 && !($(element).val())){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}, 'Partially completed rows are not allowed');


// Likert Fields
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('likert-field', {
    likert: true
});

var validator = $('.indicator-form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
        errorPos = element;
        errorClass = 'alert-arrow-center';
        error.insertAfter(errorPos).addClass(errorClass);
    }
});
```

On the face of it, this validation works - but if you start playing around with it, it becomes clear that the rule is only applied to the fields that are blank when the submit button is clicked.

How can I make it so that the validation rule applies to all fields *unless* there is no data at all?

JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6RtcJ/1/

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6KmAL/2/

Comment: That seems to be adding validation to the filled in field, rather than the missing fields.. ?  I want the rule to apply to all fields, but the message to only show when the field is empty.

Comment: missed 1 condition - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6KmAL/3/

Comment: If you put an input in the first two fields then hit submit - it works as expected.  Now delete the value from field 2.  No validation error appears, where there should be one.  Then of course, if you delete the first one, all validation errors should be removed.

Comment: can you give a specific case to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's behaving strangely because validation is only triggered for one field at a time (unless you click the submit).  If you blank out data in one field, then only the one field is re-evaluated.  This is why you have messages lingering around on other fields.

It's not ideal, but you can force the whole form to re-validate on every `keyup` and `blur` event using the `valid()` method like this...

```
$('input').on('blur keyup', function() {
    $('.indicator-form').valid();
});
```

**Your demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/6RtcJ/20/**

Same idea, but only triggered by `blur` event...

http://jsfiddle.net/6RtcJ/21/

**Quote OP**:

> *"... it becomes clear that the rule is only applied to the fields that are blank when the submit button is clicked."*

If you're expecting validation messages to appear on a field even after the same field passes validation, then that's not how this plugin works.

There are ways to group messages together using [the `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), which may help you a bit.  You can also use the `errorPlacement` callback to position the one message for the whole row.

The way the `groups` option works is that it will group all error messages for several fields into one message... so only after all fields in the group pass validation, the single message will go away.

I've set the `onkeyup` option to `false` in this example since all fields now share the same message.

**`groups` option demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/6RtcJ/22/**

Answer (score -2):

ok , i got your meaning.
there are some solution here.

1.remove the rules on this form when all input not insert any word.

2.add the rules ,if one of the input had data.

you should do a check before validation?

Comment: This doesn't allow a user to submit an empty row.  See OP.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.indicator-form').validate({
            onfocusout:false,
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                alert('Form Submited');
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Likert Fields
        /*
        $('.likert-field').each(function(){
            $(this).rules('add',{
                            required: true,
                            messages: {
                                required: "Partially completed rows are not allowed",
                            },
            });
        });
        */

        $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
            $("tr.likert").each(function(){
                var $inputs = $(this).find('.likert-field:filled');
                if (0 < $inputs.length && $inputs.length < 5) {
                    $(this).children('td').children('.likert-field').each(function() {
                        $(this).rules('add',{
                            required: true,
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                      $(this).children('td').children('.likert-field').each(function() {
                          $(this).rules('remove');
                      });
                }   
            });
        });
    });
```